# How to create a simple VPS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vps

I'm really newbie for Google Cloud Platform..i want create a really simple VPS characteristic.

So ftp, dns, email and file space.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out webmin: http://www.webmin.com/. It supports FTP, DNS, Email and file sharing